# Get last record insert time and last record delete time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance, query-performance

I need to analyze the performance of a SQL script. Is there a way to find how frequently records are inserted and how frequently they are deleted, within a given time frame? Please advice.

Comment: As currently posed, your question appears to be either unclear or too broad for a good answer.

Comment: Have you tried options provided here?: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/76efe150-4a0f-43d9-8142-625e988006f2/how-to-get-the-record-insertion-rate-in-sql?forum=sqlgetstarted